# Creating modal window for displaying videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Stuck at creating a modal window and make it pop on click. The modal items are not even displaying at my browser, but they do in JSFid. Is it the browser or is it the code? Also curious what exactly am I doing wrong, trying for quite a lot.
The HTML:

```
<section id="modals">
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <div class="modal clearfix">
                <div class="modal-menu">
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                    <div class="modal-menu-item">Video</div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">Header</div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Body</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">Footer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .modal{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
      background: gray;

    }
    .modal:before{
      box-sizing:inherit;
    }
    .modal-menu,
    .modal-content {
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    .modal-menu {
      width: 20%;
      background: #257562;
      overflow: auto;
    }


    .modal-content {
      width: 80%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      position: relative;
      background: blue;
    }

    .modal-header,
    .modal-footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
    }

    .modal-header {
      top: 0;
      background: #E85C74;
    }

    .modal-body {
      height: 100%;
      background: #F9D24F;
    }

    .modal-footer {
      bottom: 0;
      background: #752570;
    }

    .modal-menu-item {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      background: #F48829;
    }

    .modal-menu-item:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

The JS:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your scripts tags in what sequence you have included in your project?

Comment: These are bootstrap modal right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Bootstrap** modal you must include **JQuery** Library in your page and try the below code for hide/show modal::

```
$('#myModal).modal('show'); // For displaying the modal
$('#myModal').modal('hide'); // For hiding the modal
```